# React Redux ActionCreator fetch API will always hit success, even when fetch fails

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, fetch

I am building an application that works with my own API. (running nodejs server for it) and no matter what, the action creator will pass success actionCreator to reducer.

Here is my fetch action creator:

```
export function fetchData() {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(fetchBegin());
    return fetch('/api/selectAll')
      .then(handleErrors)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => {
        dispatch(fetchSuccess(json));
        return json;
      })
      .catch(error => dispatch(fetchFailure(error)));
  };
}
```

Here are the other functions in "index.js" actions

```
// Handle HTTP errors since fetch won't.
function handleErrors(response) {
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw Error(response.statusText);
  }
  return response;
}

export const fetchBegin = () => ({
  type: FETCH_DATA_BEGIN
});

export const fetchSuccess = data => ({
  type: FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS,
  payload: data
});

export const fetchFailure = error => ({
  type: FETCH_DATA_FAILURE,
  payload: error
});
```

Here is my travelReducer, I have imported the action types at the top of the file

```
const initialState = {
  items: [],
  loading: false,
  error: null
};

export default function travelReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  console.log('action :', action.type);
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_DATA_BEGIN:
      // Mark the state as "loading" so we can show a spinner or something
      // Also, reset any errors. We're starting fresh.
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true,
        error: null
      };

    case FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS:
      // All done: set loading "false".
      // Also, replace the items with the ones from the server
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        items: action.payload
      };

    case FETCH_DATA_FAILURE:
      console.log('failure should be hit');
      // The request failed, but it did stop, so set loading to "false".
      // Save the error, and we can display it somewhere
      // Since it failed, we don't have items to display anymore, so set it empty.
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        error: action.payload,
        items: []
      };

    default:
      // ALWAYS have a default case in a reducer
      return state;
  }
}
```

I then make use of this in the travelList container. I also import the fetchTravel() function and call this.props.fetchTravel() on componentDidMount()

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  data: state.travel.items,
  loading: state.travel.loading,
  error: state.travel.error
});

// // anything returned from this func will end up as props
// // on this container (this.props.fetchTravelData)
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  // whenever fetchTravelData is called, the result should be passed to
  // ALL reducers
  return bindActionCreators({ fetchData: fetchData }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(TravelList);
```

My **main** issue is not getting it to fetch as intended, it does that, but the error actionCreator never gets called, even though I can console.log "error caught" in the .catch() and it will log. But no update in the reducer.

To check this I would console.log the action.type and no matter what, even with "error caught" logging, the action type would be FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS.

Pulling my hair out, so any advice would be great.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I AM AN IDIOT :) I just checked the actionTypes I have and I realised I had fetch data success down twice, for both failure and success. I appreciate you taking the time to give advice. Marking as answered

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe your error is in the code you provided. If you are successfully logging to the console in the catch that dispatches `fetchFailure`, then you have proven that your fetch logic is working. The next debug step is likely to `console.log(error)` to make sure you are receiving what you believe you are receiving as well as `console.log(fetchFailure(error))` to make sure the action you are dispatching is what you believe you are dispatching.

If `fetchFailure(error)` is returning the error action, there is no reason for the reducer to be receiving the success action: at least not in the code that you provided.

Comment: Ok so I tried adding some extra logs and this what I got:

At the .catch() I added a log for both the "error" and the "fetchFailure(error)". From the error log I get the "internal server error" which is what I expected. However with logging fetchFailure I get the FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS type and a payload of the "internal server error". What should I look for next? the error is clearly somewhere with fetchFailure part

Comment: You possibly have `const FETCH_DATA_FAILURE = 'FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS';` instead of `'FETCH_DATA_FAILURE'`.

Answer (score -1):

Since you're throwing an error, you need to reference the [error message](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error) in your reducer instead of the error object, which is what currently gets passed to your `catch` handler.

```
case FETCH_DATA_FAILURE:
  console.log('failure should be hit');
  // The request failed, but it did stop, so set loading to "false".
  // Save the error, and we can display it somewhere
  // Since it failed, we don't have items to display anymore, so set it empty.
  return {
    ...state,
    loading: false,
    error: action.payload.message,
    items: []
```

Comment: They do not _need_ to reference the error message. They are perfectly capable of keeping and working with the Error instance. Their issue is also unrelated.

Comment: From what I understand, they want the message string in the store, whereas right now they're adding the entire error object.

Comment: My interpretation of their problem is that, despite dispatching `fetchFailure(error)`, the reducer is receiving the success action. Check the last paragraphs.